# -bash: ./catalina.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ssh, freebsd, tomcat

Using *SSH*, I want to execute `catalina.sh` to start a **Tomcat** server (from my client Mac terminal).

I log in without any issue.

Then, I do:

```
[site /home/public]$ cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin
```

and on Enter I get:

```
[site /bin]$
```

I try:

```
./catalina.sh start
```

but I get:

```
-bash: ./catalina.sh: No such file or directory
```

Edit. I don't know if this is important but I did the following:

```
[site /usr/local]$ cd apache-tomcat-8.5
[site /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5]$ cd bin
[site /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5/bin]$ catalina.sh start
-bash: catalina.sh: command not found
[site /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5/bin]$ ./catalina.sh start
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5/logs/catalina.out: Read-only file system
./catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5/logs/catalina.out: Read-only file system
[site /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.5/bin]$
```

Comment: Please add distribution. Also have you configured tomcat? Is any app working or is it a fresh setup? Is also tomcat manually deployed or a package? Which version? Please edit the question

Comment: Tomcat version is 8.5. Tomcat comes pre-configured by the hosting provider but they don't answer basic questions

Comment: Which linux distro?

Comment: It's not Linux, it's FreeBSD

Comment: Check if catalina.sh exists in that folder with ls and check what permission it has

Comment: _Of course_ it does not exist in `/bin`.

Comment: What do you expect `$CATALINA_HOME` to be (because now it's not set). Where do you set, or attempt to set, this variable?

Comment: @TrynaLearnSomethin: ls apparently returns a list of commands, not files

Comment: @JdeBP: Of course  :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda: honestly, I thought $CATALINA_HOME had been set from the hosting for me

Comment: @Guest Your question can be on the realm of a vague question because both you and us cannot guess how the provider set up things. But some providers have nice tutorials.

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 5):

> [site /home/public]$ cd $CATALINA_HOME/bin

You should not blindly follow recipes via copy and paste.  If you haven't set the `CATALINA_HOME` variable this will take you to `/bin`, which *obviously* (because it is an operating system directory) is not where Tomcat is installed on FreeBSD.

If tomcat 8 is installed from packages/ports and configured for you, the location of the directory tree will be the value of the `tomcat8_catalina_base` setting that is in `/etc/rc.conf{,.local}`.

The `sysrc` command is one of the easiest ways of displaying it:

```
% sysrc tomcat8_catalina_base
```

Starting/stopping the pre-supplied `tomcat8` service is done with the `service` command, moreover.

```
# service tomcat8 start
```

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*Wrapping Apache Tomcat in many pointless extra layers*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/tomcat.html)  The systemd House of Horror.
- https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/www/tomcat8/files/tomcat8.in?view=markup#l10

Comment: I have no /etc/rc.conf (I have etc, but there's no rc.conf inside). The command returns sysrc: unknown variable 'tomcat8_catalina_base', and I suppose this is really bad news. The craziest thing of all is my final goal is simply running a JSP page

Comment: I added another test